# CreateProcess won't start the proccess with arguments

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createprocess

So I used this code in order to start a console application with arguments:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void StartProgram(char argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    CreateProcess
    (
        TEXT("PlayerDebug.exe"),
        (LPSTR)argv,
        NULL,NULL,FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP | CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
        NULL,NULL,
        &si, &pi
    );
};

int main()
{
    StartProgram("sound.wav");
    return 0;
}
```

"PlayerDebug.exe" display the arguments used to call it. But when I run it with CreateProcess the way I showed, it doesen't display anything. I checked and in Task Manager it seems to appear, but still does not display the arguments. I also tried to write `cout << argv;` in function `void StartProgram(char argv[])` and it returned "`sound.wav`", which is correct. But it seems the argument is not passed to PlayerDebug.exe and I don't know why.
What I did wrong?
(I'm new at C++ programming)

Comment: Bit of a mess with character types here. Using `TEXT` as if you might encounter ANSI or Unicode text. But then a nasty cast to `LPSTR`. The fact the code would not compile without the cast should have alerted you to a problem. Your cast does not make `argv` actually be `LPSTR`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second parameter to CreateProcess is the full command line, not just the parameters to the EXE. Lets take two examples :

```
CreateProcess ("c:\\notepad.exe",
               "c:\\notepad.exe c:\\wibble.txt",
               ...);
```

will work fine (if there is a copy of notepad.exe and a file called wibble.txt in the root of C:), whereas

```
CreateProcess ("c:\\notepad.exe",
               "c:\\wibble.txt",
               ...);
```

will launch the EXE but fail to open the file. What this means is that when the help systems calls the second parameter the command line, it ain't lying - it wants the whole command line.

Note that you can use NULL as the first parameter if the whole command line is in the second param. That's how I normally use it in fact.

Comment: Note that the second argument must be writable memory (if calling the Unicode version), it's not safe to pass a string literal.